# Add more than one Object in method

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to add multiple objects into a NSMutableArray through a custom method? Here my code.

```
@property NSMutableArray *MusicCollectionArray;

    -(void) addPlaylist: (Playlist *) thePlaylist;
```

.

```
-(void) addPlaylist: (Playlist *) thePlaylist {
    [MusicCollectionArray addObject:thePlaylist];
}
```

Now lets say I call the method but instead of one object to add, is there a way to add multiple into one instead of calling each method separately. (the number of objects is unknown)

eg. [mycollection addPlaylist: first, second, third];

Comment: Pass an array to the method

Answer (score 0):

you can add another array like this:

```
NSMutableArray *sourceArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@"FirstObject"];

NSString *secondObject = @"SecondObject";
NSString *thirdObject = @"ThirdObject";

NSArray *objectsToAdd = @[secondObject, thirdObject];

[sourceArray addObjectsFromArray:objectsToAdd];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, please take a look at Apple docs and this thread:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1405/_index.html

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NSMutableArray (variadicMethodExample)

- (void) appendObjects:(id) firstObject, ...; // This method takes a nil-terminated list of objects.

@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (variadicMethodExample)

- (void) appendObjects:(id) firstObject, ...
{
id eachObject;
va_list argumentList;
if (firstObject) // The first argument isn't part of the varargs list,
  {                                   // so we'll handle it separately.
  [self addObject: firstObject];
  va_start(argumentList, firstObject); // Start scanning for arguments after firstObject.
  while (eachObject = va_arg(argumentList, id)) // As many times as we can get an argument of type "id"
      [self addObject: eachObject]; // that isn't nil, add it to self's contents.
  va_end(argumentList);
  }
}

@end
```

I guess you will catch an idea.

Answer (score 0):

This would best be done using a for loop:

```
- (void) addPlaylistFromPlayLists:(NSArray <Playlist*>*)playlists {
    for (Playlist *playlist in playlists) {
        [musicCollectionArray addObject:playlist];  
    }  
}
```

That way, you are ensuring that only the playlists that are inside the array are added. A for loop will only add what's given to it, you don't have to tell it how much if it's a for/in.

Comment: I like this but I'd use `addObjectsFromArray` instead of a for loop.